# Injector-error: Failed to instantiate module servicesApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem of injection of modules in angularJS:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   Mainapp due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate
>   module servicesApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'servicesApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name
>   or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify
>   the dependencies as the second argument.

Here is the service code `servicesApp.js` :

```
'use strict';

var servicesApp = angular.module('servicesApp', []);

servicesApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http',function ($http) {

    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', file);

        return $http.post(uploadUrl, data, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
          }).then(function (results) {
              console.log("done post "+results);
              return results;
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log('failed to post: ', e);
            throw e;
        });
    };

     this.upFile=function(file){

        var nameImg="";
        var uploadUrl =urlAPI+"/files/uploadFile";

        if( file != null){

            nameImg =file.name;

              this.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);

          }else{
              nameImg="userDefault.png";
          }

      return nameImg;
   };

}]);
```

Here is the directive code `directivesApp.js` :

```
'use strict';

var directivesApp = angular.module('directivesApp', []);

directivesApp.directives('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
           var modelSetter = model.assign;

           element.bind('change', function(){
              scope.$apply(function(){
                 modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
              });
           });
        }
     };
  }]);
```

Here is the Main code `Mainapp.js` :

```
var app = angular.module('Mainapp', ['ngRoute','file-model','ui.bootstrap','ngMessages','angular-loading-bar','ngFileUpload','servicesApp',
    'directivesApp']);
```

---

**Edit1:**

I changed the position of 'directives‌​App' and 'servicesApp' but I still have the same problem:

```
var app = angular.module('Mainapp', ['ngRoute','file-model','ui.bootstrap','ngMessages','angular‌​-loading-bar','ngFil‌​eUpload','directives‌​App','servicesApp'])‌​;
```

---

**Edit 2:**

> Uncaught TypeError: directivesApp.directives is not a function at
>   directivesApp.js:13

```
directivesApp.directives('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) { ..}
```

How to solve this problem?
How to use directives and services in a controller?

thank you,

Comment: show the order in index.html

Comment: how? @Sajeetharan

Comment: the file where you added reference for these js files

Comment: post it with the question

Comment: Do you have a reference to `serviceApp` in your html? `<script src="servicesApp.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you, it works @AlonEitan , but I have another problem, I updated the post (Edit2)

Comment: @Michael `directivesApp.directives` ==> `directivesApp.directive`

Comment: thanks @AlonEitan , but How to use directives and services in a controller?

Comment: @Michael You use directives in the view, and services in the controller. Just create a controller and inject `fileUpload` to its dependencies list, and you'll be able to access the service methods

Comment: Thank you very much, it works @AlonEitan , Put the answers in a 'Answer'

Comment: @Michael Thanks, please accept Sajeetharan's answer as it's exactly the same answer that I would post. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sytanx should be **`directive`**,
Change

**`From`**

```
directivesApp.directives('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) { ..}
```

**`To`**

```
directivesApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) { ..}
```